# PHP ZipArchive does not extract Hebrew files

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

When trying to extract a zip file that contains Hebrew file name, it removes the Hebrew file name from the file, or does not extract it at all.

My code:

```
<?php
 zipExtract('avi.zip','folder');

function zipExtract($src, $dest)
{

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
     if ($zip->open($src) === true) {
       $zip->extractTo($dest);
       $zip->close();
}
return false;
 }

 ?>
```

The zip file [is here](http://website100.co.il/admin/tst/avi.zip) - it was created on a Windows PC using Winrar.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? and does your filesystem support UTF8 characters in a filename ... ie can you make that file outside of PHP?

Comment: i'm using php 5.4+
the file is created on windows pc by winrar

Comment: When posting code here, please indent it carefully, so it is readable for everyone. It doesn't matter in this short example, but it can help greatly in more complex situations.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what machine the `ZIP` file has been created. From the ZIP file you've attached I can only see that it hasn't been `UTF8` encoded. Maybe you should check out [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) and try to create your ZIP file with that.